# How to find $c_2$ of the Lagrange's Equation $(x^2 + y^2)\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} + 2xy\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} + z^2 = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the equation $(x^2 + y^2)\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}} + 2xy\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} + z^2 = 0$, I have to derive a general solution in a form $\Phi(c_1, c_2) = 0$.

I wrote down a Lagrange's system of ODE

$\frac{dx}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{dy}{2xy} = \frac{dz}{-z^2}$

By using this system, deriving $c_1$ is a piece of cake.

$\frac{dx + dy}{x^2 + 2xy + y^2} = \frac{dz}{-z^2}$

$(x + y)^{-2}d(x + y) = -z^{-2} dz$

$c_1-(x+y)^{-1} = z^{-1}$

$c_1 = (x+y)^{-1} + z^{-1} $

But no matter how I shuffle parts of the system, I am unable to come up with an equation that leads to $c_2$. I either can't do anything useful with it or just get $c_1$ again.

I'll appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the solution is just under your nose, but you're thinking too complicated to notice it. Doing the math at 4 am wasn't the brightest idea of mine.

$\frac{dx - dy}{x^2 - 2xy + y^2} = \frac{dz}{-z^2}$

$(x - y)^{-2}d(x - y) = -z^{-2} dz$

$c_2-(x-y)^{-1} = z^{-1}$

$c_2 = (x-y)^{-1} + z^{-1} $

The answer is $\Phi((x+y)^{-1} + z^{-1}, (x-y)^{-1} + z^{-1}) = 0$